# Парсер таблицы html for Jsoup

Tags: java, android

У меня возникла следующая проблема. Парсишь html-таблицу, с помощью JSoup, разбиваешь на строки таблицу, а затем каждую строку на столбцы. После чего, очищаешь от  тегов и просто текст в `ArrayList` заносишь. После чего с помощью адаптера, заполняешь `GridView` в виде таблицы.

Проблема заключается в том, что все работает, когда Api lvl > 19, в противном случае вытаскиваю либо знаки вопроса, либо пустые строки.

Собственно сам код парсера:

```
Document verb = Jsoup.connect("http://passare.ru/ajax_socket.php?func=ru_verb2_forms&text=" + nWord).get();
    Element tableVerb = verb.select("table").first();
    Elements rowsVerb = tableVerb.select("tr");

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsVerb.size(); i++) {
        Element row = rowsVerb.get(i);
        Elements cols = row.select("td");
        for (Element e: cols){
            list.add(e.text().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В логах ошибок нету...

Comment: возможно это то что вы искали http://stackoverflow.com/a/7716688/2667883 и еще посмотрите вот сюда http://stackoverflow.com/a/12466923/2667883

Comment: @Chaynik Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.